# How to know the number of positions on the right of the decimal point in a float?

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm preparing some mapping sheets for migrating an actual MYSQL database to a new ORACLE one. Some of the data are defined as float, but I would like to know exactly the length of the value in the column having the maximum decimals after the point. This would help me to restrict the data type instead of declaring it as a NUMBER.

Is there an easy way to do this in MySQL? I've tried with a regular expression but it does not match all values (I've found a value like 7.34397493274) but the following regex does not retrieve it:

```
SELECT column
from `db`.`table`
where column REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{7,}$' =1;
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious - what value do you believe will be added by doing this (using a "more restrictive" type)?

Comment: Your regex matches the value with more than 7 digits after the decimal point.. Is it why it is not matching all (less than 7 digits) values? and what exactly do you want to retrieve? decimal part or length of decimal part?

Comment: Sometime ago I read something about the convenience of specifying the precission for NUMBERS in order to avoid the insert of random data

Comment: The length of the decimal part would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You are going down the wrong track.  There is no convenient answer to "how many digits are to the right of the decimal point in a floating point number".  There is an answer to the "precision" of a floating point number.  That is 23.  The relationship between precision and the numbers to the right of the floating point number depends on the scale factor.

You might want to review the documentation entitled [Problems with Floating Point Numbers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html).

More concretely, the problem is that a particular number might be represented as:

```
1.200000000001
```

or

```
1.199999999997
```

(I'm not saying these are actual representations, just examples.)  What value would you give for the numbers to the right of the decimal point?  By representing the values as floats, the database has lost this information.

Instead, you have several options:

- Just use `NUMBER`, which is generally a reasonable type.
- Use `BINARY_FLOAT`, which would be the same type.
- Understand the application to figure out how many decimal points are actually needed.
- Play games with the representation, looking for strings of zeros and nines (say four in a row) and assume they are not significant.

Comment: I think the third bullet is what OP actually needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find the length after the decimal point then in mysql you can use `substring_index` and `length` function together as

```
mysql> select length(substring_index('7.34397493274','.',-1)) as len;
+-----+
| len |
+-----+
|  11 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: the question is about floating point numbers, which are not exact representations of decimal numbers.